# Rails feature testing with logged in user (undefined method 'session')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, rspec, omniauth

I'm writing feature specs with rspec and want to skip the login step each time.  Users are authenticated through omniauth (no devise) and a `session[:user]` variable is set and then referenced to stay logged in.  I want to be able to set the session variable directly if possible:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "My page" do
  it "has what I want on it when logged in" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    session[:user] = user.id
    visit my_path
    page.should have_content "Foobar"
  end
end
```

but this gives

```
 Failure/Error: session[:user] = user.id
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `session' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007fd13456d170>
```

Is there any way to set the session variable directly so that I can avoid the login step in most of the tests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rack_session_access gem seems to work well:
https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access

With it, the test becomes:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "My page" do
  it "has what I want on it when logged in" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    page.set_rack_session(user: user.id)
    visit my_path
    page.should have_content "Foobar"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If this were a controller spec, you could simulate a login as follows:

```
request.session[user_id] = user.id
```

as indicated in [How do I simulate a login with RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121835/how-do-i-simulate-a-login-with-rspec). However, as this is a feature spec, I don't believe setting the session directly is possible.

Comment: I tried this and it threw the same error, only with the undefined method being 'request' instead of 'session'

Comment: Oh, sorry I just noticed you said _feature_ specs. I believe the above is intended for _controller_ specs. I don't believe you can update the session directly from a feature spec.