# Hartl Rails Tutorial - Having issue with undefined method 'sign_in' during tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

So I'm running through the Michael Hartl Rails tutorial and just after creating the edit page (end of Listing 9.3), I get the following errors when I run my tests.  As far as I know, I defined the sign_in method and make it available in my application controller.  Not exactly sure where I went wrong as his tutorial says my tests should pass by this point.  Any help is appreciated.  (Also, please let me know if I need to include anything else)

> Failures:
>
> 1) User pages edit page 
>        Failure/Error: sign_in user
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_4::Nested_1:0x00000108a92118>
>        # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:60:in`block (3 levels) in '
>
> 2) User pages edit page 
>        Failure/Error: sign_in user
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_4::Nested_1:0x00000108820560>
>        # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:60:in`block (3 levels) in '
>
> 3) User pages edit page 
>        Failure/Error: sign_in user
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_4::Nested_1:0x00000108846be8>
>        # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:60:in`block (3 levels) in '
>
> 4) User pages edit with invalid information 
>        Failure/Error: sign_in user
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_4::Nested_2:0x00000103e6cd60>
>        # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:60:in`block (3 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.98841 seconds
>   23 examples, 4 failures

**Test Document: user_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

    describe "User pages" do

    subject { page }
    .
    .
    .

    describe "edit" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before do
            sign_in user
            visit edit_user_path(user)
        end

        describe "page" do
            it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
            it { should have_title("Edit user") }
            it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
        end

        describe "with invalid information" do
            before { click_button "Save changes" }

            it { should have_content('error') }
        end
    end
end
```

**Session Helper: sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

    def sign_in(user)
        remember_token = User.new_remember_token
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
        self.current_user = user
    end

    def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    def current_user=(user)
        @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
        remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
    end

    def sign_out
        current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,
                                      User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token))
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
        self.current_user = nil
    end
end
```

**Application Controller: application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

Comment: Just to confirm... You're referring to the tutorial from this site (http://ruby.railstutorial.org)?

Comment: Confirmed.  Although Richard Johnson has successfully educated me in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is telling you that sign_in isn't a method in the scope of the test so you can't use it in the before block like that. It's a controller method not a test method.

Simplest approach is to create a spec helper method which does the signing in, which you can call in the context of a before block which sets up state for any test requiring a signed in user.

One way to do this would be I have a "user_signs_in" helper which uses capybara to visit signin path, fill in signin in form with correct details, and then follow redirects.

Related stackoverflow q:

[How do I simulate a login with RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121835/how-do-i-simulate-a-login-with-rspec)

Comment: Thank you.  After checking a little further in the tutorial, I noticed he does do something similar to this so I must have miss-understood the lesson.  I do appreciate the explanation though as I actually understand it much better now.  Thank you.