# Rspec test failures when trying to sign in a user with nested attributes for a parent organization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I posted a prior question asking about building a sign in model (based on the Hartl course up to section 9.2) that has a User - each user has_one Organization whereas Organizations Have_many Users. This is now working, but when I try to use factories to test my code it all starts to fall apart.

I am currently trying to set up the Organization pages so that a non-signed in user (or the wrong user) will not be permitted to see the page (as per section 9.2 of the course for User pages). I am getting the following error (which is the same error I get whenever I try to test any part of the Organization model).

```
 1) Organization Pages organization page page 
 Failure/Error: visit organization_path (organization)
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find User with 'id'=1793
 # ./app/controllers/organizations_controller.rb:22:in `correct_user'
 # ./spec/requests/organization_pages_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My organization model is as follows:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :organization_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
has_many :users

def self.organization_name
    "Something weird that no-one is likely to select on their own"
end

end
```

My User model is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :organization
accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_create :create_remember_token, :create_organization
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end

    def create_organization
        self.organization = Organization.create(:organization_name => Organization.organization_name) unless self.organization.present?
    end

end
```

My organizations controller is:

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update, :show]
  def new
    @organization = Organization.new
  end

  def show
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
  end

#before filters

def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
    store_location
  redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
  end
end

def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "You are not permitted to visit that page. Please create an account or sign in" unless current_user?(@user)
end
end
```

This is getting quite frustrating. I get the same errors when trying to use FactoryGirl created users to test other parts of the Organization model too. For completeness, here's the Factory I have created:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :organization do
    organization_name       "Example Org"
    end
factory :user do
    association :organization
    name                    "Example Name"
    email                   "an@example.com"
    password                "foobar"
    password_confirmation   "foobar"

    trait :with_org do
        organization_id     "12"
    end
end
end
```

What is strange is the fact that the FactoryGirl user keeps being created with a random Organization id (it changes every time I run Rspec but not from test to test in the same run) rather than with the trail I allocated (12). In these instances the same Rspec test failure is provided, but it says " Couldn't find Organization with 'id'=1687" or something similar.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

EDIT: adding Rspec code for completeness:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Organization Pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
  before { visit signup_path }

   it {should have_content('Organization')}
  end

  describe "organization page" do
      let(:organization) { FactoryGirl.create(:organization) }

  before do
    visit organization_path (organization)
  end

  describe "page" do
    it { should have_content("Example Org") }
  end
  end
end
```

Comment: where is Rspec code ?

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the initial listing with that code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By way of update - I solved this by changing the Organization Controller with the following code:

```
def correct_org
  @user = User.find_by_organization_id(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "You are not permitted to visit that page. Please create an account or sign in" unless current_user?(@user)
end
```

Where I changed correct_user to correct_org - and ensured that User accepts nested attributes for both the organization_name and organization_id fields.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that looks wrong in your code.

In the `organization_controller#correct_user` you are searching for users based on `params[:id]`. But the `id` parameter in a controller will typically refer to the related entity (Organization in this case), although this will of course depend on how you have set up your routes.

Also, `User.find(params[:id])` will always throw an exception if a User with the supplied id cannot be found, thus the redirect call on the second link in `organization_controller#correct_user` will never be called.

If you're trying to test of whether or not the user belongs to the current organization, you can do something like this:

```
def correct_user
  unless current_user.organization == Organization.find(params[:id])
     # redirect the user away and display an error message
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I would like the tests to be able to sign a User in and to test whether the user is part of the right Organization before showing the page. So if I am working for Nike I should be able to see other users' pages who are also employed by Nike, but not people employed by e.g. Reebok.

Comment: Are you using an authentication framework like [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), or have you cooked your own authentication mechanism?

Comment: I have been following the tutorial from Hartl - so building my own authentication mechanism using his instructions up to and including section 9.2. After that I have decided to try and learn more about writing code by adding a feature of my own - in this case Organizations - and it is working on the site now. What I can't seem to do is write effective tests for these features - probably because I'm not really understanding how the factories are created and how the test Organizations/Users are working within the Rspec framework.

Comment: I've updated the answer with code that will check if the user belongs to the current organization. As for simulating login through rspec, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121835/how-do-i-simulate-a-login-with-rspec

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm getting the error:  


 1) Organization Pages organization page page 
         Failure/Error: visit organization_path (organization)
         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `organization' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/organizations_controller.rb:22:in `correct_user'
     # ./spec/requests/organization_pages_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: It means that `current_user` is `nil`, and `nil` does not have a method called `organization`. My code was meant as an example. I don't know how you have implemented your auth mechanism, I just assumed that you would get the currently logged in user from `current_user`. Also, did you read the post on how to simulate a login trough rspec?

Comment: I did, thanks for that. I'm probably doing this the wrong way round, by letting users sign up for the site and simultaneously register an organization name. Ideally I want this to be unique - so if we both include the same organization name then we both belong to the same organization. It appears my code is creating multiple orgranizations of the same name, each with separate users at the moment.