# How do I change the default controller in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, routes

I need authentication to pass the test successfully.

```
describe PostsController do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  describe 'POST #create' do
    let(:create_post) { post :create, params: { post: attributes_for(:post) } }

    before do
      post sessions_path, params: { login: user.email, password: user.password }
    end

    context 'with valid attributes' do
      it 'return OK' do
        create_post
        expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
      end
  end
end
```

`post session_path` - this does not work and generates an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"/sessions", :controller=>"posts", :login=>"jack@example.com", :password=>"qwerty"}
```

How do I change default PostsController to SessionsController in the `before` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller specs you talk only to controller under test. If you need other controllers to create a few prerequisite objects first - create them directly in the db. If you need authenticated user - set `session[:user_id]` directly (or however it is your authentication works). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10121980/125816), for example.

What you attempted to do is called a "feature spec" (or "integration spec"). It's a different type of spec and you should write some of those as well.